# Android listview doesn't work with my Theme

Tags: android, listview, material-design, material-components-android

I've defined a Theme in my Android app based on MaterialComponents. However, the text in the listview is not the color I have defined (I want it to be white but it looks black). The text before my listview seems to pickup the right color though. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".SessionsActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.GymTimerDark" />
```

**theme.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <style name="NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.GymTimerDark" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/purple_200</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/ListViewStyleDark</item>

        <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarFullscreenTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ListViewStyleDark" parent="android:style/Widget.ListView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
    
</resources>
```

**activity_sessions.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        ...

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/customListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

    </LinearLayout>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

**SessionsActivity.java**

```
public class SessionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sessions);

        Context applicationContext = this.getApplicationContext();
        adapter = new sessionArrayAdapter(applicationContext, 0, MainActivity.importfromexternalfile(applicationContext));

        //Find list view and bind it with the custom adapter
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customListView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    
    //custom ArrayAdapter to update the visual of each elt of the listview
    class sessionArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GymSession> {  
        //constructor, call on creation
        public sessionArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<GymSession> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            ...
        }
    
        //called when rendering the list
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //get the inflater and inflate the XML layout for each item
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_sessions, null);

            ...
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

**layout_sessions.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mylinearlayoutsess"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/mygridlayoutsess3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewData_date0"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Updating..."
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewData_type0"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Updating..."
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSessionRemove"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text=" X "
            />
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried the code above but it doesn't seem to work